# HTML quebrado em algumas partes do site

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro

Em alguns pontos do site um código HTML está sendo exibido ao invés de ser renderizado:

**Indicação do autor que sugeriu uma edição**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Indicação do autor de uma [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/359200/revisions)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparentemente não é sempre que acontece. Em outras situações similares os dados aparecem normalmente.

Comment: Estava prestes a informar uma ocorrência dessa... Pelo visto, não foi só comigo...

Comment: Eu vi isso ocorrendo ontem aqui, mas no SOen não vi acontecer. Talvez seja algo que só tenha respingado nos SO internacionais

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Curioso é que as mesmas informações para usuários diferentes renderiza normalmente. Parece que caiu em uma situação bem particular.

Comment: Aparentemente o problema não está mais ocorrendo.

Comment: Ontem nos seus exemplos eu vi acontecendo... acho que estava no desktop. Hoje pelo Safari iOS não vejo mais acontecer... 

Comment: Pior que aconteceu comigo uma vez(estava acessando no celular), ao atualizar a página notei que o problema sumiu.